# "Stack overflow at line: 0" on Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, stack-overflow

My blog suddenly popup this error today, I searched around on google but still haven't found anything. But it doesn't happen on Firefox, only on IE7 and IE8.
I have deactivated all wordpress's plugins but still get the still error.

I have uploaded the screenshot

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324875/

Answer (score 2):

This is a website about technical programming questions, not for solving stack overflow errors in software :) (despite them having the same name). I suggest you contact the people who make your blog software.

Answer (score 0):

That is a javascript-Error; do you use Ads or a counter or something like that?